# MWFeedParser - RSS with images

Tags: ios, xcode, image, rss

I have problem, I'm using MWFeedParser Rss reader in my iOS aplication and it works well, but I need to fetch the images from my feed. Can you help me please?

[Here is url of that MWFeedParser project: GitHub](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used this in my cellForRowAtIndexPath function so that it searches for images as the cell is displayed

```
MWFeedItem *item = itemsToDisplay[indexPath.row];
if (item) {
    NSString *htmlContent = item.content;
    NSString *imgSrc;

    // find match for image
    NSRange rangeOfString = NSMakeRange(0, [htmlContent length]);
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<img.*?src=\")(.*?)(\".*?>)" options:0 error:nil];

    if ([htmlContent length] > 0) {
        NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:htmlContent options:0 range:rangeOfString];

        if (match != NULL ) {
            NSString *imgUrl = [htmlContent substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]];
            NSLog(@"url: %@", imgUrl);

            //NSLog(@"match %@", match);
            if ([[imgUrl lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@"feedburner"].location == NSNotFound) {
                imgSrc = imgUrl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note I am also ignoring the image if it has 'feedburner' in the url to avoid feedburner type icons.

I am also using AFNetwork's class when I show the image later

```
    if (imgSrc != nil && [imgSrc length] != 0 ) {
        [myimage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgSrc] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGETABLENEWS]];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"noimage");
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:IMAGETABLENEWS];
        //[myimage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGETABLENEWS]];
    }
```

I have left in my commented NSLog parts so you can uncomment and check if you want

Make sure you have an IMAGETABLENEWS constant for the placeholder or get rid of that part as you need.

This is only a very simple check of images in the html text and is not comprehensive. It served my purpose and may help you get your logic right for doing something more detailed.

Comment: Just one question... Is there some way to get all images form feed and not just one? Thanks :-)

Comment: thank you really  it's working . NSRegularExpression is successful .

Answer (score 1):

In case your [`MWFeedItem`](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/MWFeedItem.m) has an image embedded in it's `enclosure-tag`, you might want to consider to do the following:

`MWFeedItem` has a property called `enclosures`. It's an array containing one or more dictionaries.

This dictionaries are generated in
`- (BOOL)createEnclosureFromAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes andAddToItem:(MWFeedItem *)currentItem` ([`MWFeedParser.M`](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/MWFeedParser.m)).

These dictionaries have three keys (if available): `url`, `type` & `length`.

---

That first one is probably the one you're looking for. I managed to get it like this:

**Feed Example**

```
    <item>
        <title>Item title</title>
        <link>http://www.yourdomain.com</link>
        <description>Item description</description>
        <pubDate>Mon, 01 Jan 2016 12:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
        <enclosure url="http://www.yourdomain.com/image.jpg" length="0" type="image/jpeg"></enclosure>
        <category>Algemeen</category>
    </item>
```

*Please notice the image link inside `<enclosure></enclosure>`*

**YourViewController.m**

```
- (void)feedParser:(MWFeedParser *)parser didParseFeedItem:(MWFeedItem *)item {
    NSArray *EnclosureArray = item.enclosures;
    NSDictionary *ImageDict = [EnclosureArray objectAtIndex:0]; // 0 Should be replaced with the index of your image dictionary.
    NSString *ImageLink = [ImageDict objectForKey:@"url"];

    // Returns: http://www.yourdomain.com/image.jpg
}
```