# Viewing images in feeds parsed with MWFeedParser

Tags: objective-c

I am using [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser) to download feeds in my app. So far it's working fine - however, I am unable to parse each article for it's image URL. This is the code I have currently:

```
// MWFeedItem.h

NSData* firstImg;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData* firstImg;
MWFeedItem.m
add synthesize and dealoc
```

---

```
// RootViewController.m

- (NSString *)getFirstImage:(NSString *)htmlString{

NSScanner *theScanner;
NSString *text = nil;

theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: htmlString];

// find start of tag
[theScanner scanUpToString: @"<img src=\"" intoString: NULL];
if ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
    NSInteger newLoc = [theScanner scanLocation] + 10;
    [theScanner setScanLocation: newLoc];

    // find end of tag
    [theScanner scanUpToString: @"\"" intoString: &text];
}

return text;
}

(void)feedParser:(MWFeedParser *)parser didParseFeedItem:(MWFeedItem *)item {
NSLog(@"Parsed Feed Item: “%@”", item.title);    

NSString* str_imageUrl = [self getFirstImage:item.summary];    

item.firstImg = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str_imageUrl]];     

if (item) [parsedItems addObject:item];      
}
```

I can't view the image with this code and I'm not sure why.

Comment: You need to check whether the str_imageUrl is a full URL or relative to the website itself. You will need a full URL though to download the image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MWFeedParser - RSS with images \[XCODE\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254500/mwfeedparser-rss-with-images-xcode)

Answer (score -1):

Try [CXFeedParser](https://github.com/vgrichina/CXFeedParser). It is forked from MWFeedParser and contains an NSArray of images for every feedItem.

Comment: I get errors with that saying that certain libraries are missing.