# Having Issue with MWFeedParser thumbnail

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

Hi I am trying to display images from description to a custom UIViewCell , but the problem is thumbnail returns null ! I cannot display any image here is my code based on [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254500/mwfeedparser-rss-with-images-xcode) :

```
// Configure the cell.

    MWFeedItem *item = [itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (item) {

        NSString *itemTitle = item.title ? [item.title stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText] : @"[No Title]";
        NSString *itemSummary = item.summary ? [item.summary stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText] : @"[No Summary]";

        cell.title.text = itemTitle;
        NSMutableString *subtitle = [NSMutableString string];
        [subtitle appendString:itemSummary];





        NSString *htmlContent = item.content;
        NSString *imgSrc;

        // find match for image
        NSRange rangeOfString = NSMakeRange(0, [htmlContent length]);
        NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<img.*?src=\")(.*?)(\".*?>)" options:0 error:nil];

        if ([htmlContent length] > 0) {
            NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:htmlContent options:0 range:rangeOfString];

            if (match != NULL ) {
                NSString *imgUrl = [htmlContent substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]];
                NSLog(@"url: %@", imgUrl);

                NSLog(@"match %@", match);
                if ([[imgUrl lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@"feedburner"].location == NSNotFound) {
                    imgSrc = imgUrl;


                }
            }

        }


            [cell.thumbnails setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgSrc]
                            placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb.png"]];
          }
```

The problem is item.thumbnail returns null !

Comment: @michael waterfall would you please answer this ?

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue with this code :

```
//image
NSString *imageurl = nil;
NSScanner *theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:item.summary];
[theScanner scanUpToString:@"<img" intoString:nil];
if (![theScanner isAtEnd]) {
    [theScanner scanUpToString:@"src" intoString:nil];
    NSCharacterSet *charset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\"'"];
    [theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:charset intoString:nil];
    [theScanner scanCharactersFromSet:charset intoString:nil];
    [theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:charset intoString:&imageurl];

    imageurl = [imageurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if ([imageurl rangeOfString:@"mf.gif"].location != NSNotFound || [imageurl rangeOfString:@"sayyac"].location != NSNotFound || [imageurl rangeOfString:@"feedburner"].location != NSNotFound) {
        imageurl = @"false";
    }
} else {
    // resim yoksa
    imageurl = @"false";
}


[cell.thumbnails setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageurl]
                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb.png"]];
```

}